# wpf autocomplete with multiple entries like outlook

Tags: wpf

I wish to simulate the behavior of the Outlook - To box. The user can type in an email. Or have it suggest from a list. Additionally continue to edit existing text. And have addition emails suggested after the first email.

I looked at the WPF toolkit Autocomplete, yet it does not suggest after the first entry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: handle the preview key down event and start fresh with a ;

Comment: Not really - it was a comment not an answer.  Handle the preview key down event is where I would start.  What have you tried?